# Splitting raw image into channels in Python

Tags: python, image

I have to split raw image (.DNG) into different channels. CV does not support these formats, and I can't find rawpy function for that.

Comment: Asking for library/software recommendations is explicitly off-topic, which is what I assume you're asking, it isn't entirely clear. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rawpy` to convert your DNG into a Numpy array like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import rawpy
import imageio

with rawpy.imread('image.dng') as raw:
    rgb = raw.postprocess(gamma=(1,1), no_auto_bright=True, output_bps=16)
```

Then you can use Numpy to extract the channels and save like this:

```
# Extract Red, Green and Blue channels and save as separate files
R = rgb[:,:,0]
G = rgb[:,:,1]
B = rgb[:,:,2]

imageio.imsave('R.tif', R)
imageio.imsave('G.tif', G)
imageio.imsave('B.tif', B)
```

Or you can use **OpenCV** `cv2.split()` to separate the channels:

```
import cv2

R, G, B = cv2.split(rgb)
```

Comment: Can you also use `rawpy` to split the raw data up into its red, green, and blue components _before_ any demosaicing is performed?